# Trouble including the 'X11/Xlib.h' header file within CMake

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, clion

I am not able to get the X11/Xlib.h header file included properly with CMake on CLion. Below is the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(X11 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
add_compile_options(-Wall -lX11)

add_executable(X11 main.c)
```

And the main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xos.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The error is `undefined reference to 'XOpenDisplay'`. The `-Wall` flag works fine and I get the unused variable warning for this snippet. Lastly, I am able to compile main.c from the command line without any problem:

```
gcc main.c -lX11
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that XOpenDisplay is in `libX11.a` and linked with `-lX11`.

But maybe your `libX11.a` is not in the standard directories searched by the compiler.
On my system (FreeBSD) it is in `/usr/local/lib` and is linked with `-L/usr/local/lib -lX11`.

So, find the directory your `libX11.a` lives in and add `-L/path/to/directory` to the link command.

I don't know much about CMake, but adding link options to something named `add_compile_options` does not sound right. Is there something like a `add_link_options` directive? `-Wall` is for compilation, but `-L` and `-l` are for linking.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. The correct command as shown in the linked post is `target_link_libraries()` and adding it after CMake adds the executable.